# Angular Promises in View not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angular app, and the service is not returning the data properly.  If I console.log the `$http` callback response, I know the data is good from the web service.

However, in my app it is not displaying.  Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="main-content" class="content" ng-app="wflow-app" ng-controller="main-controller">
                <h3>Actors</h3>
                <li>
                    <ul ng-repeat=" a in actors">
                        <li>{{a}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('wflow-app', []);

app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q){
    var _baseUrl = webServiceContext;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var getActors = function(){
        $http.get(_baseUrl + '/actors').then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log("Rejected!");
            deferred.reject(response.statusCode);
    });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        getActors: getActors
    };
});

app.controller('main-controller', function($scope, dataService, $timeout) {
    $scope.servicesUrl = webServiceContext;
    $scope.actors = dataService.getActors();
});
```

Why isn't this working?

If I use this in my controller, it works:

```
dataService.getActors().then(function (data) {
    $scope.actors = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your deferred.reject?

```
$http.get(_baseUrl + '/actors').then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
 }).catch(function(response) {
         deferred.reject(response.statusCode);
 });
```

if your server is responding with a non 200 response it will never get rejected at present

i personally would just change this to ...

```
var getActors = function(){
    return $http.get(_baseUrl + '/actors');
};
```

also the result of dataService.getActors() is a promise. Thus because the return value is a promise you should call the promises THEN method as follows ...

```
dataService.getActors().then(function(response) {
        $scope.actors=response.data;
}).catch(function(response) {
        //oops
})
```

This works because $http returns a promise. The only thing $q is doing is resolving with response.data instead of resolving with response.

Comment: I added the code you suggested, but it's not making a difference.  The GET works, I just don't understand why the `$scope.actors = dataService.getActors();` part is not working\

Comment: According to Angular, if you use a promise in a view it will update the view when the promise is ready

Comment: that is true - but it gives you no control over the rejection - if the promise never resolves then you get bad behaviour. I would advise calling THEN on the dataService.getActors() method

Comment: another downside of the approach you refer to is that it makes it very hard to debug as you are now discovering - at the very least i would advise you to get it working with THEN and THEN move to your preferred approach

Comment: i have looked at it and it should work. I would advise to just return $http.post to simplify it (which returns a promise) and then try $scope.actors = dataService.getActors(); - and assuming promise resolution you should be good - hope it works :)

Comment: Understood.  I do have it working with `dataService.getActors().then(function (data) {
    $scope.actors = data;
});`, it just won't work when I switch it, and I want to figure our what I am misunderstanding.